# Layout bug: Not code related but design related

Tags: flutter, layout, widget

This time the bug i'm facing is not code related but design related. In the login page I have;

text view just saying Log In, then I have two input fields for email and password, the third widget is where the bug is. It is Forgot Password and it is constrained to the right side of the phone screen.

Now on my device, it is like "Forgot Password". But when I installed the application on another device, it went like 
"Fo
rgo
t
Pa
ss
wor
d?"

[image]

Words scattered vertically.

Here are the code screenshots,

[image]

[image]

The forgot password widget, I mentioned.
then finally the button login.

[image]

I dont know whats up? Any suggestion guys?

Comment: i would be helpful if you could provide your code and a screenshot

Comment: Hello, just updated my question @ZviKarp

Comment: Have you restarted your android studio? Invalidate Caches and Restart

Comment: Yes I did. this is btw the release apk. so I cleaned then built the release apk two times. and it gave the same result

Comment: Can you post the code instead of screenshots ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `maxLines: 1`, to your `Text` Widget:

```
Text(
   "Forgot Password?",
   maxLines: 1,
),
```

Answer (score 1):

**Remove the padding and add below code**

```
               Align(
                      alignment: Alignment(1.2, 0),
                      child: FlatButton(   // You can use your own widget here
                        child: Text(
                          "Forgot Password?",
                          style: your text style;
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
```